# A mysterious mate in one

Tags: problems, checkmate, retrograde-analysis

Here's a question that's a little off the usual format, but problem questions like this have been done before and are on topic, so here we go!

Question: Can you find the mysterious mate in one? The trick is not board rotation, removing a piece, retracting any moves, completing a move, or an illegal move-there is but one solution. Have fun solving!

```
 [Title "White checkmates Black in one move"]
 [FEN "5nRQ/6PR/1p6/p2P4/p1B5/3Pp3/8/1b1K4 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Looking at the problem as if the black King is currently invisible...

> gxf8=Q#
> All squares are now covered. So where ever the black King is hiding, the game is over.

Answer (score 15):

A solution may be that it used to be possible to

> promote to an enemy piece, as mentioned e.g. [here](https://en.chessbase.com/post/study-of-the-month-2018-07). This loophole has long been fixed in the official rules, but under old rules it was allowed to do `1. g7xf8=(black)K` which would be mate.

Would that really explain

> the [retrograde-analysis](/questions/tagged/retrograde-analysis) tag?

Perhaps, in the sense that

> we *do* need to go back in time.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy.

> The Black king is somewhere on the 8th rank. It is checkmated in one move by pawn x knight on f8, queening. Now the new queen is giving check, and the rook on h7 prevents the king from going anywhere, resulting in checkmate.